# Bluetooth: Page Timeout during pairing

Tags: bluetooth, embedded-linux, bluez

This error `org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed: Page Timeout` shows up during the pairing of a device and pairing never succeeds. Using 4.14 kernel and Bluez 5.46. how / where to change this timeout?